# Autoit: Creating a Function?

Tags: autoit

I have a GUI that records the list of all the chm in a folder. When 'RUN' button is clicked, it will open the first chm in the list until so on. Then I have created a function that should expand the tree.

My problem is my function, it works until `MsgBox()` and stops there. When I ran my program there is no error indicated.

```
#include <GuiConstantsEx.au3>
#include <GuiListBox.au3>
#include <GuiTreeView.au3>
#include <File.au3>
#include <Array.au3>

;GUI
$guiTitle = "Automation"
GUICreate($guiTitle, 250, 430)

Global $hWnd = ControlGetHandle("[CLASS:HH Parent;TITLE:AutoIt Help]", "", "[CLASS:SysTreeView32; INSTANCE:1]")
Global $hChild = _GUICtrlTreeView_GetFirstChild($hWnd, 0)
Local $source = InputBox("Source Folder","Please enter the source folder","")

;InputBox
If @error = 1 Then
   Exit
EndIf

If @error = 4 Then
   Exit
;GUI_List
Else

   $add = GUICtrlCreateButton("Show", 10, 53, 230, 20)
   $picList = GUICtrlCreateList("", 10, 78, 230, 300)
   $run = GUICtrlCreateButton("Run", 170, 385, 70, 30)

   GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)



   While 1
       $msg = GUIGetMsg()
       Switch $msg
            ;add
           Case $add
               Global $FileList = _FileListToArray($source, "*.chm")
               If @error = 1 Then
                   MsgBox(0, "", "No Files Found.")
                   Exit
               EndIf
               If @error = 4 Then
                   MsgBox(0, "", "No Files Found.")
                   Exit
               EndIf

               For $i = 1 To $FileList[0] ;List_IFIX Pictures
                   GUICtrlSetData($picList, $FileList[$i])
                Next

            ;run
           Case $run
               If _GUICtrlListBox_GetCount($picList) = 0 Then
                      MsgBox(0, "", "No Files Found.")

                   Else 
                     For $i = 1 To $FileList[0]
                        If Not WinExists("AutoIT Help]") Then
                           ShellExecute($source & "\" & $FileList[1])
                           _Expand($hWnd, $hChild)
                        EndIf
                        Next
               EndIf

            ;exit
           Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
               ExitLoop
       EndSwitch
   WEnd
EndIf
```

And here is my function:

```
Func _Expand($hWnd, $hChild)
   WinWaitActive("AutoIT Help")
   MsgBox(0,"","Expand")


   While 1
       $hChild = _GUICtrlTreeView_GetNextChild($hWnd, $hChild)
       If _GUICtrlTreeView_GetText($hWnd, $hChild) = "Tutorials" Then ExitLoop
   WEnd

   _GUICtrlTreeView_Expand(ControlGetHandle("[CLASS:HH Parent;TITLE:AutoIt Help]","", "[CLASS:SysTreeView32; INSTANCE:1]"),$hchild, True)
 EndFunc
```

Comment: No error indicated? Well that syntax definitely isn't valid, I can see a `For` without a `Next`, and `Else Exit` on one line. The snippet you have provided doesn't show the value of `$hChild` when passed to `_Expand`.

Comment: Is it possible that `WinWaitActive("[CLASS:AcrobatSDIWindow]")` waits forever? Try put `WinActive("[CLASS:AcrobatSDIWindow]")` (or WinActivate or what the function name is, I dont remember)

Comment: I cut some lines. I just edited it now and change the file to open to .chm instead of .pdf

Comment: `WinWaitActive("AutoIT Help")` should be `WinWaitActive("AutoIt Help")` (lower-case 't')

Comment: You should learn by your mistakes and don't repeat the same error over and over again. So before you ask the next (hopefully more specific) question, you should consider checking for the same old traps and whether you fall into one of these pits again.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of problems with the code.

1. Check your titles! In two cases you have got the window title spelt incorrectly in your example. AutoIt is spelt with a lowercase *t*, and window title matching is case sensitive unless you set an option otherwise.
2. If "Tutorials" is not found then you will loop forever. You should add a check after `_GUICtrlTreeView_GetNextChild` to see if you've reached the end of the treeview.

But the real problem with your code is that you are setting `$hWnd` and `$hChild` at the beginning of the code, before you run the process that creates the window. As a result, the window is not found, and so $hWnd will always be NULL when you call `_Expand`.

This sort of question is not encouraged on stackoverflow. We like questions which will be useful to other people in the future rather than help with specific code. Before asking questions like this in the future, please try and debug the problem yourself. You could add `ConsoleWrite` statements through the code showing variable values, which would have shown you that `$hWnd` didn't have a handle value when you enter expand, from there it is obvious.